# Error With ISTool after compiling

Tags: installation, compiler-errors, inno-setup, istool

When I test my setup.exe file I get the following error message:
**This program cannot be installed on Windows NT Version 5.1.2600 Service Pack 1 or later.**

Why is this happening, I am running Windows 8 Dev Preview too. Could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've got an OnlyBelowVersion directive in your [Setup] section that is limiting it.
From the InnoSetup documentation:

> [Setup]: OnlyBelowVersion
>
> Format:    a.bb,c.dd, where a.bb is the Windows version, and c.dd is
>   the Windows NT version.
>
> Default value:     0,0 Description:
>
> This directive lets you specify a minimum version of Windows or
>   Windows NT that your software will not run on. Specifying "0" for one
>   of the versions means there is no upper version limit. Build numbers
>   and/or service pack levels may be included in the version numbers.

From http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_onlybelowversion